# couchbase subdocument arrayAddUnique not working for non string objects

Tags: java, couchbase, subdocument

**GOT this error The unique value provided is not a JSON primitive**

arrayAddUnique
public  AsyncMutateInBuilder arrayAddUnique(String path,
                                               T value,
                                               boolean createParents)

If i pass value as a string it works.
Example - arrayAddUnique("path", "value", false)

But if i pass value as an Object I get can't insert error.  MultiMutationException
Example - arrayAddUnique("path", someobject, false).execute();

Comment: Please add SDK, Language, Enviornment etc.

Comment: arrayAddUnique(String, T, boolean) in com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc